# android:elevation для api <21 или Как сделать тень у элементов RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть RecyclerView с такими элементами:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/competition_card_shadow">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/positionLV"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_card_left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speciality_points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"
            tools:text="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorOrange"
            android:text="@string/place"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_card_right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/positionLV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speciality_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            tools:text="Геодезия" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/speciality_plan"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_tag_green"
                tools:text="Топ-30"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/speciality_status"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreyDark"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_orange_text_view_corners"
                tools:text="Зачислен"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/speciality_order"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:paddingStart="4dp"
                android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_order_text_view"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:text="ПРИКАЗ"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

competition_card_shadow.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorBlackTransparent"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Выглядит это так:
[image: Картинка вьюхи]

Тень при помощи цвета смотрится убого. При том, что хочется сделать тень вокруг всей вьюхи, а при помощи цвета это будет смотреться как обводка.

ViewCompat.setElevation() не работает (в качестве вьюхи передавал linearLayout).

Нарисовать градиентом - градиент нужен специфичной формы, на данный момент я не смог придумать градиент такой формы, чтобы тень нормально смотрелась.

Буду благодарен всем, кто обратит внимание на проблему.

**РЕШЕНИЕ:**

Благодаря добрейшим и уважаемым людям в комментариях, проблема решилась так:

- Корневой LinearLayout теперь CardView из библиотеки
  `com.android.support:cardview-v7`.
- Добавлены атрибуты
  `app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"` и
  `app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"`

Comment: а почему не использовал `cardview` для элементов `recyclerview` там бы и задал `app:elevation`?

Comment: @iFr0z в проекте используются зависимости v27.1.1. Эмнип CardView ввели с v28.0.0. Раз других вариантов нет - придётся переносить проект на другие зависимости. В последний раз у меня это не получилось. Вдруг получится сейчас...

Comment: @SibPathfinder, никаких проблем с `CardView` у вас не будет! Используйте его!

Comment: Не совсем понял, в чем сложность с v27.1.1, но вот `com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1`